# Reference a row name in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, namespaces, row

I've a simple VBA script to hide / show a row based on another cell's value.  But I can't seem to reference the row based on a name.. only on the row number (which changes as I add other stuff!)

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("CB10.2")) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value
    Case Is = "Yes": Rows("36:36").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Else: Rows("36:36").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End Select
End If
```

I'd like to do something like this but get a 'Type missmatch':

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("CB10.2")) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value
    Case Is = "Yes": Rows("CB10.3").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Else: Rows("CB10.3").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End Select
End If
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reference rows by named range, so just replace

```
Rows("CB10.3").EntireRow.Hidden
```

With

```
Range("CB10.3").EntireRow.Hidden
```